# Помогите новичку с регуляркой на php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть фраза "высота|толщина кровати(слова "кровати" может и не быть) 21 см (или нет см.)"

Нужна регулярка которая получит сантиметры. 
Спасибо.

Comment: `/\s+([0-9]+)( см)?$/` - например, так. В первых круглых скобках будут см. Как поймать в переменную - зависит от языка, на котором пишете.

Comment: На php)  а как указать пробел /возможно слово/ пробел ?

Comment: `/ (слово )?/` - вот так, с помощью вопросительного знака.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, `/.*(\d+).*/` должно работать -- просто выделяет из строки подряд идущие цифры, отбрасывая всё остальное.

Comment: Проблема в том, что в строке можно быть больше разного текста.

Comment: Да хоть сколько. Он весь будет проигнорирован. Возьмите да попробуйте, недолго же. У меня просто нет php, я не могу на нем порробовать.

Comment: По вашим вопросам складывается впечатление, что вы даже не пробовали что-нибудь по регуляркам почитать. Если так - то попробуйте, полезно.

Comment: регулярка с см намного лучше: не захватит цифры, если они встретятся.

Comment: @AK так человеку нужны именно цифры, а "см"  у него может быть и может не быть с одинаковым успехом.

Answer (score 0):

```
%(?:высота|толщина)[^\d]*\b(\d+)\b%iu
```

`(?:высота|толщина)` начинает поиск от подстрок `высота` или `толщина`, они могут быть не словами; `?:` обозначает, что группу не надо захватывать в результат;

`[^\d]*` - от нуля и больше символов не являющихся цифрами;

`\b` - граница слова, в данном случае - перед цифрой не стоит буква или `_`;

`(\d+)` - 1 группа захвата состоящая из цифр, которые вам нужны;

`\b` - граница слова, в данном случае - за цифрой не стоит буква или `_`;

Модификатор `i` - регулярка регистро-независимая

Модификатор `u` - обрабатываем текст в кодировке UTF-8

Тест https://regex101.com/r/zPlsQZ/1